# Mongoose populate with 2 Files and 2 Collections return empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the problem that my populate query returns an empty array. I am aware of the countless posts, however none of them provided new insights for me.

My first Schema:
station.js

```
var stationSchema = new Schema({ 
    _id: Number, 
    Tripcount: [{ type: Number, ref: 'Tripcount'}]
},
    {collection: 'stations'}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Station', stationSchema);
```

My second: trips.js

```
var tripSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    Tripcount: Number
},
    {collection: 'trips'}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tripcount', tripSchema);
```

And my query looks like this, according to the majority of the answers this should do the job:

```
var Station = require('./station.js');
var query = Station.find()
        .populate({
            path: 'Tripcount',
            model : 'Tripcount'
        });
        query.exec(function(err, stations){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(stations);
        });
```

Using Postman to GET the stations, it shows `Tripcount: []`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would add another answer based on previous comments. It seems that your data is not linking up. Mongoose populate will take the values in Station's Tripcount array and try and lookup the Tripcount object in the Tripcount collection using the _id field so lets say you have the following station

```
{
  _id: 1,
  Tripcount: [100, 101, 102]
}
```

In your Tripcount Collection you will need the following to match up with the Station Above

```
[
  {
    _id: 100,
    Tripcount: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 101,
    Tripcount: 4
  },
  {
    _id: 102,
    Tripcount: 6
  },
]
```

Then when you run your query you will get the following

```
{
  _id: 1,
  Tripcount: [
    {
      _id: 100,
      Tripcount: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 101,
      Tripcount: 4
    },
    {
      _id: 102,
      Tripcount: 6
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But there is no tripcount array in the station collection, maybe I didn't make that clear. It should use the _id from station collection to match _id from tripcount collection. I think I have to use findById.

Comment: Well then your reference will have to be to Station from the Tripcount collection and you would have to transpose your query

Comment: So like Trip.find().populate with the station?

Comment: Yes or have a look at the $lookup mongodb documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Thanks a lot, great help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following. Pass an empty object to your find method.

```
var Station = require('./station.js');
var query = Station.find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'Tripcount',
            model : 'Tripcount'
        });
        query.exec(function(err, stations){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(stations);
        });
```

Comment: And you are sure you have data in your database?

Comment: Yes, I am using mongo-express also, so I can see what I am working on. I also checked only fetching the Tripdurations, so only changing the query, which does work. It's populating what doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you remove the populate portion of your query?

Comment: It returns the station data according to the station schema.  The tripduration is in another collection.

Comment: Can you confirm that the station's Tripcount value matches an id in the Tripcount collection?

Comment: Hm, no it doesn't, is the query suggestion so? Each station has an id, and the tripcount collection has an id and a count entry, it should just match station id with tripcount id and populate the tripcount.

Comment: That would be your problem. Populate will use station's Tripcount value to lookup the _id in the Tripcount collection.

Comment: Thank you, lots of insights in this. What needs to be changed to let it use the id, the schema or the query? I just assumed it would use the id.

Comment: It is your data. I have added another answer